# Play Framework : Run test on multiple drivers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, playframework, specs2

I use PlayFramework 2.3 and specs2 to write functional tests.

In the documentation, there is the following example

```
"run in a browser" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(HTMLUNIT), app = fakeApplicationWithBrowser) {
…
}
```

How to run this test against multiple drivers ?

I currently use :

```
def drivers: Seq[String => WebDriver] = ...

examplesBlock {
  for (driver <- drivers) {
    "run in a browser" in ((s: String) => new WithBrowser(d(s)) {
…
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better (simpler) way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've came up with a cleaner solution, by extracting the logic in a `trait`

```
trait MultiBrowser {
  self : Specification =>

  def drivers : Seq[String => WebDriver]

  def browsers(u: (String => WebDriver) => Unit) = examplesBlock {
    for (driver <- drivers) {
      u(driver)
    }
  }
}
```